# Scraping rating stars by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape rating by stars.

I've researched and looked around but most of the codes are incomprehensible to me.  This is my code when I attempted to scrape but the result is none. Can you please tell me where I was wrong?

This is the page I've been scraping:https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send GET request
r = requests.get('https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk=')

# Parse HTML text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# def scrape_tiki(url="https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk="):

# Get parsed HTML
#     soup = get_url(url)


product = soup.find('div',{'class','product-item'})

rating = product.find('span',{'class':'rating-content'})
print (rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting `class="rating-content"` you can try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Send GET request
r = requests.get('https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk=')

# Parse HTML text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
# def scrape_tiki(url="https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789?src=c.1789.hamburger_menu_fly_out_banner&_lc=Vk4wMzkwMTUwMDk="):

# Get parsed HTML
#     soup = get_url(url)

cnt = 1
product = soup.find_all('div',{'class','product-item'})
# print(product)

for i in product:
    # print(i)
    rating = i.find('span', class_="rating-content")
    print(rating)
```

Comment: Thanks sir for the suggestion. it does extract the data, but is there a way to these into numbers?ie: If a product is 5 star icons, it appears 5